# What went wrong with my Mysql to MairiaDB migration fail ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql, migration, mythbuntu, mariadb

This is on a 16.04 Mythbuntu (upgrade from 14.04, 12.04, 10.04) backend ( I have five systems already running MariaDB)

with guidance from [MariaDB Foundation (interactive) Downloads Setting up MariaDB Repositories](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=digitalocean-sfo&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=xenial--ubuntu_xenial&version=10.1) *Ubuntu; 16.04 LTS "xenial"; 10.1 [Stable]; DigitalOcean - San Francisco, US*

and also  [MariaDB Foundation How to migrate from MySQL to MariaDB on Linux in five steps](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-migrate-mysql-mariadb-linux-five-steps)

Repository:

```
~$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
Executing: /tmp/tmp.D33DjUJPH2/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys
--keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
gpg: requesting key C74CD1D8 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key C74CD1D8: public key "MariaDB Signing Key <signing-key@mariadb.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
~$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el]   http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu xenial main'
```

Stopped mysql.service, then installed with apt

```
~$ sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

Failed with:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.1_10.1.25+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Full output @ [1st pastebin](https://pastebin.com/f0ZvHkHe)

2nd try with 'apt-get' vice 'apt' & then 'apt-get -f install' @ [2nd pastbin](https://pastebin.com/kkH7CH5C)

A similar fail with somewhat more effusive output.

I was apparently mislead regards to the simplicity.

Comment: Try removing `mysql-server-core-5.7` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jos](https://askubuntu.com/users/149708/jos) suggested removal of mysql-server-core-5.7 is required, and I found complete removal of all mysql turned the trick

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then install mariadb, and then it was required to set up the databases and users before the sql backups could be restored.

All in all reasonably done.